Why is it legal that YouTube counts multiple clicks by the same person on a video as views?
The most watched video on YouTube is a kids song with 15 billion views. That’s more than two times the people on earth. The viewcount doesn’t count because we can’t know how many people actually watched it. It’s just an excuse to gather popularity and rise through the rankings—maybe even monetize the video with the ads, if they’re lucky. What if they employ fake views?

Why the 'viewcount doesn't count'? Sure, it could be one person watching it 15 billion times (well, not really), but if you have ever had kids you would know that they love seeing the same thing over and over and over again if they like it. So, 30 million kids watching it 500 times each is quite plausible.

YouTube almost certainly keeps "unique viewer" counts as well, and I'll bet it makes this information available to content providers and advertisers. It's just not in the public view counts.

Youtube is free to establish whatever rules it wants in contracts with content providers. They don't have to be the most wise rules possible. It might want to do so because it is easier to just record views without keeping track of who is viewing the video posted.
Orchestrating fake views may be a breach of either the express terms of the contract, or the general duty of good faith and fair dealing that applies to all contracts. It is up to Youtube to decide how to deal with the situation.

There could be issues with advertising and trading laws if the video tries to sell something or the count is used in advertising ("See why 200 billion people learned about our revolutionary product")

@user71659 Only if the person inaccurately describes what the count is counting.

In other words: A user has no standing to bring a lawsuit against the video producer: they are not harmed.

Views =/= clicks. Many people have it on endless repeat, to keep the little kid quiet.
Click once, view 20 times.
